# Unable to start appdesigner

Tags: linux, matlab, matlab-app-designer

I'm trying to run matlabs appdesigner, but I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'appdesservices.internal.browser.AbstractBrowserController' class
destructor:
Undefined function 'isvalid' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in appdesservices.internal.browser.WebWindowController/closeBrowser (line 127)
            if isvalid(obj.WebWindow) && obj.WebWindow.isWindowValid

Error in appdesservices.internal.browser.AbstractBrowserController/delete (line 51)
            obj.closeBrowser();

Error in appdesservices.internal.browser.WebWindowController (line 28)
        function obj = WebWindowController(varargin)

Error in appdesservices.internal.peermodel.BrowserControllerFactory/launchWebwindow (line 81)
            browserController = appdesservices.internal.browser.WebWindowController(varargin{:});

Error in appdesservices.internal.peermodel.BrowserControllerFactory/launch (line 73)
            browserController = obj.CallbackMethod(varargin{:});

Error in appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignerWindowController/startBrowser (line 96)
            obj.BrowserController = obj.BrowserControllerFactory.launch(initialBrowserState);

Error in appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignEnvironment/startAppDesigner (line 151)
                obj.AppDesignerWindowController.startBrowser(inputArguments{:});

Error in appdesigner (line 62)
appdesigner.internal.application.getAppDesignEnvironment().startAppDesigner(filePath); 
> In appdesservices.internal.browser.WebWindowController (line 28)
  In appdesservices.internal.peermodel.BrowserControllerFactory/launchWebwindow (line 81)
  In appdesservices.internal.peermodel.BrowserControllerFactory/launch (line 73)
  In appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignerWindowController/startBrowser (line 96)
  In appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignEnvironment/startAppDesigner (line 151)
  In appdesigner (line 62) 
Error using matlab.internal.webwindow (line 275)
Unable to start MATLABWindow process

Error in appdesservices.internal.browser.WebWindowController/startBrowser (line 70)
            webWindow = matlab.internal.webwindow(browserOptions.URL,...

Error in appdesservices.internal.browser.AbstractBrowserController (line 47)
            obj.startBrowser(browserOptionsStruct);

Error in appdesservices.internal.browser.WebWindowController (line 30)
            obj = obj@appdesservices.internal.browser.AbstractBrowserController(varargin{:});

Error in appdesservices.internal.peermodel.BrowserControllerFactory/launchWebwindow (line 81)
            browserController = appdesservices.internal.browser.WebWindowController(varargin{:});

Error in appdesservices.internal.peermodel.BrowserControllerFactory/launch (line 73)
            browserController = obj.CallbackMethod(varargin{:});

Error in appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignerWindowController/startBrowser (line 96)
            obj.BrowserController = obj.BrowserControllerFactory.launch(initialBrowserState);

Error in appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignEnvironment/startAppDesigner (line 151)
                obj.AppDesignerWindowController.startBrowser(inputArguments{:});

Error in appdesigner (line 62)
appdesigner.internal.application.getAppDesignEnvironment().startAppDesigner(filePath);
```

I'm using Arch Linux and I installed Matlab 2016b, I've also installed the libraries listed in the AUR matlab package, with no success. I also installed the ncurses5 package and have oracle-jdk8 installed. How can I fix the error?

Comment: What is the code you're running? Just `appdesigner`? Or are you trying to load some existing AppDesigner app? The error might mean that the `uifigure` handle is stored as a `double` (this is something typically encountered in older MATLAB versions), seeing how `isvalid` is a method of graphical objects... By default, MATLAB R2016b (at least on windows) uses `Java 1.7.0_60-b19` (see `version -java`).

Comment: This is caused vy just typing appdesigner in the matlab prompt

Comment: Try running `dbstop if error` before `appdesigner` then, when it breaks, what are the contents of `obj.WebWindow`? It says in the function that this code is executed when "_MATLABWindow process can be killed unexpectedly, like from Task Manager or Linux kill command_". Could it be that something on your system kills the webwindow before it's ready?

Comment: I don't manually kill the window and don't have any specific software installed that I know of that would cause that. The only value that seems to be of significance in obj.webwindow seems to be the URL: `https://localhost:61415/toolbox/matlab/appdesigner/web/index.html?CWD=%2Fhome%2Fuser%2F&ShowIntroDialog=true&ShowCodeViewTips=true&ShowAxesBanner=true&ShowCompatibilityDialog=true&ShowProgrammingTips=true&snc=8DBBFD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like matlab requires the [libselinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libselinux/) package to work. (in Matlab 2016b) Had the same error as you did, and fixed it by installing that package.

Comment: thanks! that helped, however when opening a window I'm getting "Unable to get WebGL context", did you get that error as well?